# Share with Anyone option is disabled

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365, administration, external-sharing

I want to share one folder anonymously but **Anyone** option is disabled. How can I enable it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that in SharePoint Admin Center below settings are enabled:

1. Enable Anonymous sharing globally using below settings

[image]

2. Enable Same setting for your site as well

[image]

Comment: Thanks Kalpesh. It worked

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the external sharing settings for making this option
(Anyone) available while sharing with other users.

> SharePoint has external sharing settings at both the organization level and the site level (previously called the "site collection" level). To allow external sharing on any site, you must allow it at the organization level.
>
> You can then restrict external sharing for other sites. If a site's external sharing option and the organization-level sharing option don't match, the most restrictive value will always be applied.

Check below Microsoft official documentations for same:

1. [External sharing overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/external-sharing-overview)
2. [Manage sharing settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/turn-external-sharing-on-or-off)
3. [Change the sharing settings for a site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/change-external-sharing-site)